Fourier Transform of Gaussian times Error Function
I'm looking to evaluate the integral,
\begin{align}
\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} \mathrm{d}s \: e^{-its} e^{-s^2} \mathrm{erf}(s)
\end{align}
This table of integrals has a closed form for the related integral,
\begin{align}
   \int_0^{+\infty} \mathrm{d}x \: \sin(bx) \mathrm{erfc}(ax) e^{a^2x^2} = \frac{\sqrt{\pi}}{2a}e^{-b^2/4a^2}\mathrm{erfc}(\frac{b}{2a})
\end{align}
but it's not quite in the same form due to the requirement that the coefficients in erfc and the exponent are the same (also it is an ''inverted Gaussian''). This answer Integral of error function times Gaussian also has a very close integrand, but with a complex argument for the error function, and therefore makes use of a very specific result for the Hilbert transform of a Faddeeva function. One thought was to write the error function as the sum,
\begin{align}
\mathrm{erf}(z) &= \frac{2}{\sqrt{\pi}} \sum_{n=0}^{+\infty} \frac{(-1)^n z^{2n+1}}{n!(2n+1)}
\end{align}
but the Fourier transform of $e^{-s^2} s^{2n+1}$ is not particularly elegant (i.e. sums of hypergeometric functions), and then the infinite sum is no more concise.

I believe I have a nested series representation if you're interested, but are you looking for a closed form?

Hi @StevenClark, a closed form would be nice, but perhaps a nested series representation is a step towards that.

There is a nice expression even for a slightly more general integral. Let
$$
f \colon \mathbb{R}^2 \to \mathbb{R}, \, f(a,b) = \int \limits_0^\infty \sin(ax) \operatorname{erf}(bx) \mathrm{e}^{-x^2} \mathrm{d}x \, .
$$
Since
$$
\operatorname{erf}(bx) = \frac{2}{\sqrt{\pi}} \int \limits_0^{bx} \mathrm{e}^{-t^2} \mathrm{d} t \overset{t = b x u}{=} \frac{2}{\sqrt{\pi}} b x \int \limits_0^1 \mathrm{e}^{-b^2 x^2 u^2} \mathrm{d} u \, ,
$$
we can change the order of integration and integrate by parts to solve the $x$-integral in terms of the well-known Fourier transform of a Gaussian to obtain
$$
f(a,b) = \frac{2}{\sqrt{\pi}} b \int \limits_0^1 \int \limits_0^\infty \sin(a x) x \mathrm{e}^{-(1 + b^2 u^2) x^2} \mathrm{d} x \, \mathrm{d} u = \int \limits_0^1 \frac{a b \mathrm{e}^{-a^2/4(1+b^2 u^2)}}{2(1 + b^2 u^2)^{3/2}} \mathrm{d} u \, .
$$
This integral is much nicer than it looks though, as the substitution $u = \tan(v)/b$ reveals:
$$
f(a,b) = \frac{a}{2} \int \limits_0^{\arctan(b)} \mathrm{e}^{-a^2 \cos^2(v)/4} \cos(v) \mathrm{d} v = \frac{a}{2} \mathrm{e}^{-a^2/4} \int \limits_0^{\arctan(b)} \mathrm{e}^{a^2 \sin^2(v)/4} \cos(v) \mathrm{d} v \, .
$$
Letting $a \sin(v) = 2 w$ and using the definition of the imaginary error function, we finally find
$$
f(a,b) = \mathrm{e}^{-a^2/4} \int \limits_0^{ab/2\sqrt{1+b^2}} \mathrm{e}^{w^2}  \mathrm{d} w = \frac{\sqrt{\pi}}{2} \mathrm{e}^{-a^2/4} \operatorname{erfi} \left(\frac{a b}{2 \sqrt{1 + b^2}}\right).
$$
In particular, your Fourier transform is
$$
-2 \mathrm{i} f(t,1) = - \mathrm{i} \sqrt{\pi} \mathrm{e}^{-t^2/4} \operatorname{erfi} \left(\frac{t}{2 \sqrt{2}}\right) \, .
$$

Hello @ComplexYetTrivial! Thanks for this concise answer. I've used your result as part of the answer to a nested integral I am trying to compute, which gets me to the even more nasty looking form, $\int_a^{+\infty} \mathrm{d} z : e^{-cz^2}\mathrm{erf}(idz) e^{-ibz}$. Do you have any guidance on this latter integral? If it makes things easier, you could set $b = c = d = 1$

Ok, for more context, the final integral I want is $\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} \mathrm{d}z :\mathrm{sign}(z) e^{-c(\Omega-z)^2} \mathrm{erf}(id(\Omega - z ) \sin(b z)$ for which I made some manipulations (including splitting up the integral for the domain of $\mathrm{sign}(z) > 0 , < 0$).

I believe the Fourier transform
$$g(t)=\mathcal{F}_s\left[e^{-s^2}\, \mathrm{erf}(s)\right](t)=\int\limits_{-\infty}^{\infty} e^{-s^2}\, \mathrm{erf}(s)\, e^{-i t s} \, ds\tag{1}$$
can be evaluated as
$$g(t)=f\left(-\frac{t}{2 \pi}\right)\tag{2}$$
where
$$f(x)=\frac{1}{4} i \lim\limits_{N\to\infty} \sum\limits_{n=1}^N \frac{\mu(2 n-1)}{2 n-1}\\ \lim\limits_{f\to\infty}\sum\limits_{k=1}^{2 f (2 n-1)} \left(\left(4 (-1)^k \cos\left(\frac{\pi k}{2 n-1}\right)-1\right) F\left(\frac{k}{4 n-2}\right) \sin\left(\frac{\pi k x}{2 n-1}\right)\\+F\left(\frac{2 k-1}{8 n-4}\right) \sin\left(\frac{\pi (2 k-1) x}{4 n-2}\right)\right)\tag{3}$$
and
$$F(s)=e^{-s^2}\, \mathrm{erf}(s)\tag{4}.$$

In formula (3) above $\mu(n)$ is the Möbius function and the evaluation frequency $f$ in the inner sum over $k$ is assumed to be a positive integer. Formula (3) above is a refinement of formula (12) in my related MSO question which provides information on its derivation.

Figure (1) below illustrates $\Im(g(t))$ evaluated using formulas (1) and (2) above in blue and orange respectively where formula (1) is evaluated using numeric integration and formula (3), referenced by formula (2), is evaluated at $N=10$ and $f=4$.


Figure (1): Evaluation of $\Im(g(t))$ using formulas (1) and (2) in blue and orange
